# Cocos2d button touch areas

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Is there an easy way to specify a touch area Rect for a CCMenuItem (i.e. not the default contentSize dimensions).

Some of my buttons are a bit small to touch and I'd like to increase the touch area without scaling the graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use the following:

`[CCMenuItem setContentSize:newSize];`

Where CCMenuItem is the item's touch area you want to expand and newSize is the new width and height.

Another choice is to create a child class of CCMenuItem and override the corresponding responsible method.